# TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

i am trying to make a fish command but it always says

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: 
Command raised an exception: 
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple
```

heres my fish code

```
@client.command()

async def fish(ctx):
  user = ctx.author
  users = await get_bank_data()
  amount = random.randint(1,2)
  inv = users[str(user.id)]["inv"]
  for thing in inv:
    n = thing["item"]
    if "fishingrod" in n:
      amt = thing["amount"]
      fishamount = ["fish"],["amount"]
      if amt > 0:
        await ctx.send(f"You found {amount} fish")
        fishamount += amount
      if amt < 0:
        await ctx.send("You don't have a fishing rod!")
```

please help me with my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you declare `fishamount` with `fishamount = ["fish"],["amount"]` so you set it to a tuple which has two lists in it, which each have one string in it:

```py
(["fish"],["amount"])
```

but the you try to use the `+` operator on the tuple and the int `amount`, which can't work since you can only add integers to integers and tuples to tuples.
You have to decide what you want to store in the variable.